# How to properly work with responsiviness in React's Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new with the framework, and I've been using react-bootstrap since then.

For what I understand, Material-UI does not provide a GRID system, so I provided react-flexbox-grid for my application. But the Material-UI's component doesn't seem to respect the grid size. Here is how I'm using it:

```
import React from 'react'
import MenuContainer from '../containers/MenuContainer.jsx'
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar'
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid'

const IndexComponent = ({children}) => (
  <Grid fluid>
    <Row>
      <Col xs={12} md={12} center="xs">
        <AppBar 
          title="Comics Index"
          showMenuIconButton={false}
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Col xs={12} md={3}>
        <MenuContainer width="100%" />
        {children}
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Grid>
)

export default IndexComponent
```

And my second question is: how do I make a navbar that collapses on mobile using Material-UI? I can't seem to find any directions for that and all Material-UI's components looks like not responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material UI have implemented their own Flexbox layout.

It is currently only in the [next branch](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/releases)
There are some examples with code [here](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/layout/grid)

You can install it by specifying next when installing material-ui

```
npm install material-ui@next
```

As for your second question Material design specifies that your navigation should come from a sidenav. This is why its not implemented in Material Design frameworks. See [here](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation.html) for more informaton

Comment: If you are using Typescript they currently do not have typings released for the Grid.